# SAML logout not working in ADFS

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, logout, adfs, adfs3.0

I have written a Service Provider and testing the same with some IDPs. When I tested with ADFS, login works fine but have a problem during logout. When I set a logout request, I am getting a valid logout response from the ADFS but when I send a new AuthNRequest after successful logout, ADFS is not asking for any credentials and making the user previous logged-in as the current user and sending a valid Auth Response with the same. Here is the LOGOUT RESPONSE sent by ADFS :

```
<samlp:LogoutResponse ID="_4b1507e9-85c6-4aab-8a20-9bf420f15057" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2018-01-24T10:16:46.793Z" Destination="https://manoj-3374:9876/mc/SamlLogoutResponseServlet" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="ME_7d8bc526-b585-460e-a677-cab2c9f4c43b" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://hostname/adfs/services/trust</Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ds:Reference URI="#_4b1507e9-85c6-4aab-8a20-9bf420f15057"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>pLbKQReWhLBgYkDMe4ets84pnQq21NexmofA/49bBXQ=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>oq60dpAGnAUdjmLFUFZDIcc/LZo5dhxVgc12nMUdAmffl3CgMXXOUvdprUaAWkf84gTZ2zaHb0iIHDRIjjicrfR1NunmgT9/dpP0rHvDJ5ViCyb6Lf7eWomyDqAAvpWGL9MwHIpW0tQZj04DxYbMzRJrwyvCClKO8IQ+xin09wSXcU5Ibm7l/75FZB/ZNI35e/PietCL6Rt8uf/YjH4sYthIYzTBn70iYAElO87YFvVBP0RtK0vv5WpcvnxaGh0eWDnYAYJHEIZQ/EjZFCEVfuneqL2F9n3uXQR9FW2N9Kb3mdKy74PSh/Qbsosq3efZ7sC5DXUcVseJIrJTynpBrw==</ds:SignatureValue><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></KeyInfo></ds:Signature><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" /></samlp:Status></samlp:LogoutResponse>
```

Comment: did you manage to achieve what you were expecting ? If so, please do guide me, how you did achieve it

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I was trying with wrong Algorithm. Signed with one and configured a different one. Once that is fixed, issue did not seem to occur.

Answer (score 0):

How did the user login? Were they a domain user and they used Windows integrated authentication?

If so, the logout response will indicate success even though the user wasn't logged out from Windows.

If they used forms authentication then they should have been logged out.

In that case, you should check the ADFS Windows event log for more details.

Comment: When logging-in for the first time, browser prompted for user credentials. while re-login , browser didn't ask for any credentials.

How to find whether it used IWA?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the Windows event log on the ADFS server for error entries.